# How to export / import certain rows?

Tags: mysql, import, export

I have such a table (for games) in my database:

```
 id   name   playcount
---- ------ -----------
 1    game#1  17
 2    game#2  22
```

etc, and field playcount has attribute `DEFAULT 0;`
So, say I want to re-create this database, by exporting all the fields except playcount.

How can I do this? a phpmyadmin solution is ok. Thanks !

Comment: Please edit your post to include one of your attempts, and folks will point you in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `INTO OUTFILE` on this, to produce `CSV` format

```
SELECT  id, name, 0 AS playcount
        INTO OUTFILE 'backup.txt'                       -- this is the location
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM TableName;
```

to load the file back, use [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'backup.txt'
INTO TABLE TableName
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```